# Execute code when user ends process of application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, event-handling

I'm in the process of creating a program that monitor's user activity however I realized that a IT inclined user such as myself would simply end the process from the task manager so in response to that I want to create a second project that runs concurrently with my first application so that If a user ends the process in my task manager then this is logged in a database and the user is prompted to start my application. I know how to check for running processes so at first I thought I would just search for my application in the task manager and if its not there my code would fire up however I don't know where to add the code and how to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you need is a windows service that will check once in a while if the process of your app is still alive otherwise it will raise a warning message.

Comment: Ok so How would you go about creating a service

Comment: I can not provide you with the actual code but here are 2 great starters if you wish to create a windows service: MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) and CP (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample)

Comment: i know how to create a service i mean how can i connect my service to my application and where in my service would i write the code for it